# Using jest with tensorflow.js produces error

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, jestjs

I receive an error when I try to run tensorflow.js with jest. I import the node backend and it immediately errors. If I run normally (not using jest) then I get no such error.

```
FAIL  src/policy.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

    > 1 | import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
        | ^
      2 | import {slide} from './util.js';
      3 | import * as R from 'ramda';
      4 | 

      at new PlatformBrowser (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/platforms/platform_browser.ts:26:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/platforms/platform_browser.ts:42:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/index.ts:29:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/src/index.ts:18:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js:33:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/policy.js:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/policy.test.js:1:1)
```

I am wondering why this issue occurs and if I can work around it. If jest uses node internally for testing (right?) then the tensorflow node backend should work when imported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this to my package.json

```
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

Apparently jest runs in a browser-like environment by default

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your environment because you need the browser-like environment, you can just mock the tensorflow module.

```
jest.mock('@tensorflow/tfjs');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to change the environment settings inside the tfjs runtime so that it uses the correct polyfill.  These settings are controlled in TensorFlow with a singleton environment variable (`ENV`) which you can access from the function `env()`.

```
import { env } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-core";
```

In your Jest tests, you can call following code to tell tfjs that it is not in a browser.

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  env().set('IS_BROWSER', false); // Fixes TensorFlow error `ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined`
});
```